# Debugging a two way binding through an ng-init not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

**How can I console.log a mustache'd variable`{{scope}}` into the `ng-init` to debug 2 way binding/scoping from the view?**

**html:**

```
<div ng-init="omg({{svglayout(key).width}})"></div>
```

**js:**

```
$scope.omg = function(evt) {
   console.log(evt);
};
```

I know there are lots of other ways to do this but i'm trying to make sure that data is properly scoped from the markup and it's not pilot error...

By using console.log I'm able to test the markup easier because there are a lot of fixed position elements.

**Update:**
If i remove the interpolation no error is thrown but it comes up `undefined`
The object isnt undefined for I know if I go

```
<p style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; top:0; left:0; height: 500px; width: 500px background: #fff;">{{svglayout(key)}}</p>
```

this has results:

```
{"width":707.912457912458}
```

and the svglayout function:

```
scope.svglayout = function(idx) {
  var newWidth = (scope.windowHeight-clearanceSetter)*      (scope.adPageData.pages[idx].imagewidth/scope.adPageData.pages[idx].imageheight);
  return {

      width: newWidth

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the string interpolation

```
omg(svglayout(key).width)
```

Comment: it's coming up undefined but I'm pretty sure thats not true.  Still testing.

Comment: Updated the question above to show the removal of string interpolation isnt the answer.

Comment: What is the function of `svglayout`

Comment: My best guess is that there's a problem somewhere else in your code. Is `scope.adPageData.pages` populated immediately when you run the controller or are you making some sort of http request to get the data for it?

Comment: What is correct? I just made a statement and asked 2 questions haha.

Comment: adPageData is coming form an Http get request.

Comment: Ah! Okay well your problem is much deeper then. `svglayout` is actually throwing an exception in your view, but AngularJS doesn't report it, which then returns `undefined`.

Comment: ahh yeah.  I guess theres no simple way to wait for this with out waiting for page load or setting some kind of promise/timeout.  or is there???>>

Comment: If you want to assign the result to a variable, just call `.then(function (resultOfPromise) { ...` on the http request